# Sound while turning wheel all the way. Just replaced struts and sway bar links

Tags: suspension, jetta, alignment

I have a 2010 jetta limited edition. I was told that the front coil springs were broken so they needed to replace the struts. While replacing struts, the mechanic said that the sway bar end link got chipped off and needed to be replaced too. I got that done. They also said that they did an alignment check and did not need to do an alignment because it was not off by much after it.

Now when I turn my wheel all the way to the left in a lot, I hear a clicking noise. And when I turn the wheel all they way to the right, I hear a grinding noise. This issue was not there before the replacement.

Can someone explain what may have gone wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: often times when you hear noise while turning the wheel, the CV joint is the culprit but after reading your question, I doubt that it is the problem. I feat that the shop may have done a shoddy job in your car.